# Не могу запустить процессы concurrent.futures с асинхронной функции

Tags: python, asyncio, coroutine

Есть такой код:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


async def test1(text: str):
    for _ in range(2):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(text.upper())


async def test2(text: str):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(text.lower())


async def test(text: str):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(text.lower())


async def main():
    futures = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        future1 = executor.submit(test1, "lored")
        future2 = executor.submit(test2, "hello")
        future3 = executor.submit(test, "nono")

        futures.extend([future1, future2, future3])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

При запуске выдает 3 одинаковые ошибки:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'test' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Экзекьюторы предназначены в первую очередь для запуска синхронного кода асинхронно (в отдельном потоке или процессе). Экзекьютор первым параметром должен принимать обычный callable объект, например, синхронную функцию, а вы передаете асинхронную.

Асинхронная функция при обычном вызове (без `await`) возвращает не результат, а awaitable объект, но в дочернем процессе `await` от этого объекта не вызывается, из-за этого фактически функция не запускается и выходит предупреждение, что она `was never awaited`.

В целом, если убрать весь асинхронный синтаксис и заменить `await asyncio.sleep` на `time.sleep`, все заработает:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def test1(text: str):
    for _ in range(2):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(text.upper())


def test2(text: str):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(text.lower())


def test(text: str):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(text.lower())


def main():
    futures = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        future1 = executor.submit(test1, "lored")
        future2 = executor.submit(test2, "hello")
        future3 = executor.submit(test, "nono")

        futures.extend([future1, future2, future3])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Вывод:

```
LORED
hello
LORED
hello
hello
nono
...
```

---

Чтобы работало в асинхронном `main` с асинхронным синтаксисом, нужно использовать [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) вместо `submit` (тогда можно будет, например, принудительно дожидаться завершения задачи через `await future1`). Но опять же, функции `test1`, `test2`, `test` остаются синхронными.

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time


def test1(text: str):
    for _ in range(2):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(text.upper())


def test2(text: str):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(text.lower())


def test(text: str):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(text.lower())


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    futures = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        future1 = loop.run_in_executor(executor, test1, "lored")
        future2 = loop.run_in_executor(executor, test2, "hello")
        future3 = loop.run_in_executor(executor, test, "nono")

        futures.extend([future1, future2, future3])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

---

Чтобы запускать асинхронные функции из экзекьютора, их нужно запустить через `asyncio.run` (точно так же, как вы запускаете `main` из основного процесса). Можно написать общую запускающую синхронную функцию, и из нее уже вызвать асинхронные:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time


async def test1(text: str):
    for _ in range(2):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(text.upper())


async def test2(text: str):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(text.lower())


async def test(text: str):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(text.lower())


def wrapper(async_func, *args):
    asyncio.run(async_func(*args))


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    futures = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        future1 = loop.run_in_executor(executor, wrapper, test1, "lored")
        future2 = loop.run_in_executor(executor, wrapper, test2, "hello")
        future3 = loop.run_in_executor(executor, wrapper, test, "nono")

        futures.extend([future1, future2, future3])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Ещё вопрос появился, из этих задач можно как-то дождаться результата выполнения функций и потом уже получить return?

Comment: @Printon если нужно дождаться завершения futures, то `await asyncio.gather(*futures)`